# How to compute posterior predictive distribution given only the sample mean, sample size and the range of values?

Tags: posterior, density-estimation

Suppose the only information I have about a variable $x$ is as follows:

- The mean, $\bar{x}$
- The sample size, $n$
- The values used to calculate $\bar{x}$ were from a particular interval that ranges, say, from $a$ to $b$. In other words, this is a truncated distribution.

Here is what I need:

- Step 1: Compute posterior distributions for the parameters of a suitable underlying distribution, about which we know that:

  - its sample mean is $\bar{x}$
  - $\bar{x}$ was calculated based on $n$ observations (however, the observations themselves are unavailable to us)
  - the distribution is constrained, i.e. its values can only vary from $a$ to $b$
- Step 2: Using the above posterior distributions of parameters, simulate a predictive distribution of $\tilde{x}$
- Step 3: Use that predictive distribution of $\tilde{x}$ in further analyses.

To put this into context, the problem relates to a product's ratings given by customers at a website. Those ratings can only vary from 0.1 to 5.0 (yes, on a continuous scale). I know that the average rating is, say, 3.5, and this value is based on, say, 50 votes (but I don't know the individual ratings). Essentially, my task is to reconstruct the most likely distribution that generated the original unobserved ratings. I'm not sure it's possible given the limited information at hand, but I'd love to hear experts' opinion.

One of the options I was thinking about is to use a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) to approximate the original distribution of ratings. From the practical point of view, that might do. However, how could I incorporate the uncertainty about the mode (i.e., $\bar{x}$) in my simulations (i.e., how could I take into account the sample size that my sample mean is based on)?

Comment: Are you sure $x$ can be normally distributed if it is sampled from an particular interval $[a,b]$? Maybe you should clarify if you are talking about a truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @muffin1974, you are right - it's better to rephrase it to truncated distribution. I've updated the question

Comment: You should state more precisely what you are interested in: I suppose you mean $x\sim N(\bar{x},\bar{\sigma}^2)$, where you have no knowledge w.r.t. variance of $x$. However, the posterior predictive distribution requires (as the name says) the posterior distribution of the variable, therefore you have to precisely state your prior distributions for the unknown parameters. Have a look at {http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573694/bayesian-posterior-with-truncated-normal-prior}[this question] first, maybe it helps!

Comment: @muffin1974, apologies for not being clear enough - I'm no expert in this area and admittedly can be phrasing things weirdly. You are correct in your formulation of the problem. And yes, defining the prior distributions for the unknown parameters is the key here. The link you provided seems to be relevant but, unfortunately, I cannot get may head around as to how I could translate that into, say, R code.

Comment: Based on the title I would have thought that this is about a (conditionally iid) sample from which the observation themselves are censored and only sample mean, sample size, minimum and maximum are reported. Based on the question text and the comments, this is about something else. If there is some practical application, it might help to explain the problem in the application terms, too. In any case, could you at least post some example data (containing both hidden and observed information).

Comment: @JuhoKokkala, again apologies for the unclear formulation of the problem and potentially incorrect use of terminology. I've updated the question, trying to explain it better.

Comment: Ok, given the example this is now reasonably clear. However, you may want to remove the claim that the variable is normally distributed (since it is not normal and it seems you are willing to consider other possibilities than truncated normal). You don't have to write in the "Original question. Update. Update 2. ..." format.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala thanks for your kind suggestions and confirming that the problem formulation is more clear now. As I cannot come up with a better wording though, I think I'll keep the 'Gaussian distribution' for now, even though it's a truncated one

Comment: So you are not interested in other models?? I think truncated Gaussian may be somewhat difficult to handle since the distribution of the sample mean of iid. truncated Gaussians is not truncated Gaussian. Or at least (I suspect) it is not any more analytically tractable than using any other distribution. I would propose deleting everything else from the question and explain that you want to do Bayesian modeling for the problem where only the sample mean (and sample size) of ratings (constrained in $[0,5]$ ) is observed and that you want to get a posterior predictive for next individual rating

Comment: ^ Though if that is not what you are interested in, then I still do not understand the question.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Thanks again - I'm already learning a good deal from your comment. Please check now if it makes more sense.

Comment: To get anywhere you would need to make some assumptions about the standard deviation $\sigma$ by making the prior for this parameter informative.  But bear in mind that data is not going to tell you much if anything about $\sigma$ if you only observe $\bar x$.  Also, as noted by @Juho, the distribution of the sample mean of truncated normals would be a complicated convolution so it might be easier to deal with $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ as latent variables and then sample from the joint distribution of these and $\mu$ and $\sigma$, perhaps using Gibbs sampling.